# LibreOffice Writer Export to PDF is Destroying Original Document

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

Recently I've had a few documents that I've needed to convert from .odt to .pdf formats and naturally I use the "Export to PDF" option in the File menu. The exporting works just fine, creating a PDF document just like I'd expect, but then when I go back to the original document all of the content is garbled up like it was thrown into a shredder. This doesn't seem to happen every time, but its already happened to me about a half-dozen times.

The first time this happened, I obviously didn't expect it and the only editable copy of this document was destroyed. Now any time I want to convert to PDF I have to make a copy of the document beforehand or else risk my only editable copy useless.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, or how I might stop it?

Comment: What precisely do you mean with "but then when I go back to the original document". You mean open the file after having closed it?

Comment: No, its immediately destroyed. I don't even have to close it and try to reopen it for the content to be messed up; it's just messed up as soon as the export takes place. But yes, even if I close the file and reopen it, the file is still messed up.

Comment: Add the full version info of your Libreoffice version and of your Ubuntu version to the post. The terminal command `lsb_release -a` will provide info on the operating system, Help - About in Libreoffice will provide the version number.